# Combining Strategies in a Java Strategy Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

Examples below are shamelessly ripped off of [java.dzone.com](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-strategy), and modified to suit my needs:

Our interface:

```
public interface CompressionStrategy
{
  public void compressFiles(ArrayList<File> files);
}
```

Our First Implementation

```
public class GZipCompressionStrategy implements CompressionStrategy
{

   public File compressFiles(ArrayList<File> files)
   {
     //using GZIP approach
     return archive;
   }

}
```

Our Second Implementation:

```
public class TarCompressionStrategy implements CompressionStrategy
{

   public File compressFiles(ArrayList<File> files)
   {
     //using TAR approach
     return archive;
   }

}
```

And this is the use given:

```
public class CompressionContext
{
   private CompressionStrategy strategy;   

   //this can be set at runtime by the application preferences
   public void setCompressionStrategy(CompressionStrategy strategy) 
   {
       this.strategy = strategy;  
   }

  //use the strategy
   public File createArchive(ArrayList<File> files) 
   {
        strategy.compressFiles(files);
   }

}
```

Client Class with Main method

```
public class Client
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      CompressionContext ctx = new CompressionContext(); 
      File archive;
     //we could assume context is already set by preferences 
      ctx.setCompressionStrategy(new TarCompressionStrategy());     
     //get a list of files 
    ...
     archive = ctx.createArchive(fileList);    
     ctx. setCompressionStrategy(new GZipCompressionStrategy());
     archive = ctx.createArchive(archive);         
   }
}
```

Which feels messy, because:

1. I'm having to reset the strategy each time
2. The Two strategies may or may not be compatible (in that order, e.g. does it make sense to Tar a GZipped file?)
3. Creating a third TARGZipStrategy class is ok in principle, but if we had 10 strategies allowing for every other one to be part of a valid XXXCombinedStrategy method, we'd have ~35 different classes.

Is there a neat way to arbitrarily run multiple strategies sequentially within this pattern? For instance if I wanted to create a `.tar.gzip` file at the end?

What I'm trying to say is there neat way to combine two strategies together into one?

I feel like what I'm doing should have some neat solution and I don't want to reinvent the wheel, and at the same time I don't want to fall into being too reliant on patterns.

Comment: You mean a `decorator` ?

Comment: You're probably looking for the decorator pattern or the composite pattern.

Comment: @JBNizet a composite strategy?

Comment: @Pureferret: yes; as in the JoinedCompressionStrategy shown in the response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could create a `JoinedCompressionStrategy`

```
class JoinedCompressionStrategy implements CompressionStrategy {

    private final CompressionStrategy s0;
    private final CompressionStrategy s1;

    public JoinedCompressionStrategy(CompressionStrategy s0, CompressionStrategy s1) {
        this.s0 = s0;
        this.s1 = s1;
    }

    public File compressFiles(ArrayList<File> files) {
        File archive = s0.compressFiles(files);
        return s1.compressFiles(Arrays.asList(archive));
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this, the OP can chain together any number of other-strategies

Comment: Maybe you can even change this to a list and allow usage of n strategies instead of 2?

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` doesn't return `ArrayList`, besides if i want to make a `.zip.tar.7zip`  how can i do it?

Comment: @nachokk I think you could use varargs? You method becomes: `public JoinedCompressionStrategy(CompressionStrategy ... s)`, and s is treated as an array.

Comment: @nachokk also, if you changed the compression method to `compressFiles(Files .. files)` and it would take ArrayLists and Arrays.

Comment: It's nice, but still a bit imperative style. I would do it more declaratively by creating composite of strategies and injecting this single object to your client, thus relievieng it from the responsibility of combining intermediate results.

Answer (score 4):

You probably are looking for a [decorator pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html) implementation instead. The intent of this pattern is to add additional responsibilities dynamically to an object. Tradeoff is that you'll get a explossion of subclasses too.

Example with code:

The common interface.

```
   public interface CompressionStrategy{
       File compressFiles(List<File> files);
   }
```

the base compression for all files.

```
public class CompressionBase implements CompressionStrategy{

    @Override
    public File compressFiles(List<File> files)) {
        //return default compression
    }

}
```

The decorator abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractCompressionDecorator implements CompressionStrategy{

    private final CompressionStrategy decoratee;

    /**
     * @param decoratee
     */
    public AbstractCompressionDecorator(CompressionStrategy decoratee) {
        super();
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
    }

    @Override
    public File compressFiles(List<File> files) {
        File file = decoratee.compressFiles(files); 
        return compressFilesToAnotherFormat(file);
    }

    protected abstract File compressFilesToAnotherFormat(File file);


}
```

and the decorators concrete classes.

```
public class TarCompression extends AbstractCompressionDecorator {

    public TarCompression (CompressionStrategy compressionStrategy) {
            super(compressionStrategy);
    }

@Override
protected File compressFilesToAnotherFormat(File file) {
    // tar compression logic here;
}
```

}

Zip compression

```
 public class ZipCompression extends AbstractCompressionDecorator {

    public ZipCompression (CompressionStrategy compressionStrategy) {
            super(compressionStrategy);
    }

@Override
protected File compressFilesToAnotherFormat(File file) {
    // zip compression logic here;
}
```

and a simple Factory to create objects

```
public final class CompressionFactory {

    private CompressionFactory (){}

    public static CompressionStrategy create(String extension){

        CompressionStrategy compressionStrategy = new CompressionBase();        

            if(extension.contains("zip")){
               compressionStrategy = new ZipCompression(compressionStrategy);
            }else if(extension.contains("tar.gzip")){
               compressionStrategy = new TarCompression(new GzipCompression(compressionStrategy));
            }

        return compressionStrategy ;
    }
}
```

then in client code you only have to write this.

```
CompressionStrategy compressionStrategy = CompressionFactory.create("tar.gzip");
File file = compressionStrategy.compressFiles(files);
```

Comment: @Pureferret see edit, this is a more robust solution, here you add functionality , you can make it with `zip.tar.7zip.whatever` you add functionality dinamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TgzCompressionStrategy implements CompressionStrategy
{
     TarCompressionStrategy tar = new TarCompressionStrategy();
     ZipCompressionStrategy zip = new ZipCompressionStrategy();

    public File compressFiles(ArrayList<File> files)
    {
        File archive = tar.compressFiles(files);
        archive = zip.compressFiles(archive); // need to handle archive is not array list, but you can do that
        return archive;
    }

}
```